# How to remove an item from ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I'm using an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>` to store items in. I know how to add an item to this list, but I don't know how to remove one. I've tried many things, such as `list.remove(position);` but nothing was working. I've searched on Google and read tons of similar questions which didn't help me at all.
My question is: How to remove an item from the list?

My list:

```
[
    { title=MyFirstElement, comments=First element of my list },
    { title=ASecondOne, comments=Two elements },
    { title=Third, comments=Never two without three }
]
```

Comment: Do you mean how to remove a special `Map.Entry`? How do you want to remove it, by key or by value? What's given?

Comment: I'd like to remove the whole first element using the position.

Comment: *I've tried many things, such as `list.remove(position);` but nothing was working*, what wasn't really working? How did you infer that? Do explain.

Comment: I've tried to do `list.remove(position);` when clicking on the item of my ListView. I get the position of the element in my listview and then use it in `list.remove(position);` and was getting an error "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT"

Comment: The error you had concerns JSON, not really what you explained in your question. Putting that aside, just removing form a list is as easy as what you tried, list.remove(index). 
You may have a JSON parsing problem somewhere else, misleading you.

Comment: You can create a custom model class including the title and comments and then use `list.remove(position)` if you are willing to do it without using the hashmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please post the complete stacktrace. The eror you have mentioned is not relate to what you think. Its something relates to Json.

In general,

> list.remove(index)

should work in your case.